# sorting months in R with count or summarise

Tags: r

I am trying to sort months with R and have the following:

````
```{r}
result <- mydata %>%
count(months(as.Date(orderdate)))
result
```
````

This results with the monts and a count of the orders. However, the months are not ordered correctly by month. How can i sort this correctly by month?

I already did try to use "order" and "factor", however this was not working correctly. How can i use a short code and order correctly?

Thanks,

Roland

Comment: Welcome to SO! Kindly share data using `dput`. Have a fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have no sample data provided, I can't test if it really works in your specific case. Converting your months-data to a factor works, but you'll have to specify the names of the months first (in the language of your data), as R doesn't know how you want them to be ordered. Thus, creating a factor without defining the levels will only lead to alphabetical order, which isn't correct for months.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- mydata %>%
  mutate(ordered_months = factor(months(as.Date(orderdate)), 
                                 levels=c("January", "February", ...))) %>% # insert all month-names here
  count(ordered_months)
result
```

...should work.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick ;-) I just needed to change the month names to my local language and now it is working with the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
count(
  factor(months(as.Date(orderdate)), month.name)
)
```

since `months()` *"return[s] a character vector of [month] names in the locale in use"* and is a less brittle solution than hard-coding U.S./English month names.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes your locale speaks the English language. This is because the built-in variable `month.name` uses English month names.

First of all, make up a dataset, since you have not posted one.

```
set.seed(1)
d <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by = "month")
mydata <- data.frame(orderdate = sample(d, 1e2, TRUE))
```

Now the problem. Note that `order` is its own inverse, the fact that this answer uses.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


result <- mydata %>%
  count(months(as.Date(orderdate)))

inx <- order(month.name)
result[order(inx), ]
```